# How to freeze a thread in VSCode during C++ debugging

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-code

I've been using VSCode to coding for months. It's really awesome! However, I found I'm not able to freeze one thread. All I can do is `Pause(all threads)` and `Continue(all threads)`. Without freezing a specific thread, it's difficult to debug a multi-threaded program, especially some bugs that will only occur with a particular order.

Does VSCode have this feature in C++ debugging?

Comment: What tool-chain are you using VSCode is just an GUI ?  For example WinDbg supports this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-n--suspend-thread-

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for reply! I used VSCode on Mac but usually ssh to Linux. So I think I should check the command of gdb and use the command in `Debug Console`?