# Any way to pause only one thread while debugging Python in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

When I debug a multi-threaded Python program using vscode, I found all threads were suspended when a breakpoint is hitted. Is there any way to choose to suspend only one thread or all like what Pycharm does?

Comment: thats a strange requirement. Can you tell the reason for this?

Comment: Speaking for myself, this can be a problem when you have communication threads that are expected by a client app to be active. In my case, I'm communicating with a robot that implements a heartbeat protocol. If 1000ms passes without a response, it closes the connection.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP. Need to pause a single thread without also pausing keep-alive thread. The current solution seems to be to use Pycharm because you can do this in Pycharm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369644/how-to-freeze-a-thread-in-vscode-during-c-debugging 

Same question for C++